# Controlling an instance's state with AtomicBoolean

Tags: java, concurrency, lifecycle, atomic-values

I need to ensure that a particular start and stop code is executed only once per instance lifecycle, and that the instance cannot be "restarted". Is the following code adequate for a scenario where multiple threads may be acting upon the instance?

```
public final class MyRunnable {
    private final AtomicBoolean active = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private final AtomicBoolean closed = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public void start() {
      if (closed.get()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Already closed!");
      }
      if (active.get()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Already running!");
      }

      active.set(true);

      // My one-time start code.

      // My runnable code.
    }

    public void stop() {
      if (closed.get()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Already stopped!");
      }
      if (!active.get()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Stopping or already stopped!");
      }

      active.set(false);

      // My one-time stop code.

      closed.set(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `closed.set(false);` I suppose you meant this to be `closed.set(true);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go with a single 3-valued status for two reasons.

Firstly, out of the 4 possible values of the `active,closed` "tuple" only 3 make sense, setting both to `true` results in a (possibly benign, but nevertheless) invalid state. You may dismiss it as pure pedantry, but a clear design often brings other benefits.

This leads us neatly to the second, scarier reason:

```
 active.set(false);
 // <-- what if someone calls start() here?
 closed.set(true); //I assume you wanted to set it to true
```

As you can see from my comment, you've got a vulnerable spot there, someone could conceivably call `start()` after you've set `active` to `false` but before you set `closed` to `true`.

Now you may just say "okay, let's swap the two then and set `closed` first", but then you have to explain why the two would definitely not be reordered by the JVM. And you'll end up with potentially both flags set to `true`, resulting in the "invalid state" outlined above.

There is another, separate problem here: the pattern you follow is to call `get()` to check the value and then `set()` it to something else later. As [PetrosP pointed it out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36086011/574479), this isn't an atomic operation, you can call `start()` a 1000 times with all of them seeing `active` as `false`. You need to use `compareAndSet` instead, which **is** atomic (this is the whole point of the `Atomic*` classes), and thus guarantees that only one thread can ever advance the status flag.

So let's combine the two, using a single 3-valued status (I've used  `AtomicInteger` for simplicity, but you can use `AtomicReference` and a true `enum`) and `compareAndSet()`:

```
public final class MyRunnable {
    private static final int READY_TO_START = 0;
    private static final int ACTIVE = 1;
    private static final int STOPPED = 2;
    private final AtomicInteger status = new AtomicInteger(READY_TO_START);

    public void start() {
      if (!status.compareAndSet(READY_TO_START, ACTIVE)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Already started");
      }

      // My one-time start code.
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (!status.compareAndSet(ACTIVE, STOPPED)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Can't stop, either not started or already stopped");
        }

      // My one-time stop code.
    }
}
```

Comment: A small nit - it's guaranteed (in a correct compiler) that the two `AtomicBoolean.set()` calls won't be reordered, as they both translate to `volatile` stores. There should be a `StoreStore` barrier between these: http://g.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov Yes, it is guaranteed, but what I meant is that it isn't immediately obvious just from looking at the code. I've clarified that bit.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is not sufficient. Consider tis scenario: Two threads go in start() at the same time. One calls `active.get()` and it gets `false` returned. Then the second one calls `active.get()` and it gets `false` as well. In this case they will both continue. Then the first one will set active to true. The second one at that point will also set active to true, and they will both continue to the rest of the code that should be run once.

A solution could be this:

```
public final class MyRunnable {
    private final AtomicBoolean active = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private final AtomicBoolean closed = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public void start() {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (closed.get()) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Already closed!");
            }
            if (active.get()) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Already running!");
            }

            active.set(true);
        }

        // My one-time start code.

        // My runnable code.
    }

    public void stop() {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (closed.get()) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Already stopped!");
            }
            if (!active.get()) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Stopping or already stopped!");
            }

            // My one-time stop code.

            closed.set(false);
            active.set(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This fixes the problems but if you put `synchronized` around everything, you lose the benefit of using the `Atomic*` classes.

Comment: Yes you are right. I was just about to write a comment that your solution is better by far. Unfortunately I cannot upvote it because I do not have enough reputation :-)